# PySpark Deciling UDF Not Giving Output & Taking Lot of time to Run

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cumulative-sum, pyspark-pandas

So basically I have created a PySpark function named segmentation that performs cumulative sum calculation, handles outliers, finds the maximum cumulative sum, calculates a decile, and updates a column based on specific conditions.
Here is how it should work -

1.Create Window Specification:
Define a window specification for ordering based on specified columns in descending order.
Calculate Cumulative Sum:

2.Add a new column (CUM_SUM) to the DataFrame, representing the cumulative sum of a specified column over the defined window.

3.Handle Outliers (Conditional Update):
If the provided outlier value is not equal to 1000000:
Subtract the sum of (col_nm) values greater than or equal to the specified outlier from the CUM_SUM column.

4.Calculate Maximum Cumulative Sum:
Find the maximum value of the CUM_SUM column across the entire DataFrame.

5.Calculate Decile:
Add a new column (col_name2) to the DataFrame, calculating the decile based on a specific formula.

6.Update Values:
Modify values in the col_name2 column, setting values equal to 11 to 10.
Return the Modified DataFrame:

Return the DataFrame with all the calculated and updated columns.

Here is my code-

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum, when, ceil
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

def segmentation(df, col_name, col_name2, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, outlier):
    window_spec = Window.orderBy(
        col(row1).desc(),
        col(row2).desc(),
        col(row3).desc(),
        col(row4).desc(),
        col(row5).desc(),
        col(row6).desc()
    )

    # Calculate cumulative sum using a Window function
    df = df.withColumn("CUM_SUM", sum(col(col_name)).over(window_spec))

    # Check if outlier is not equal to 1000000 and perform the conditional update
    if outlier != 1000000:
        df = df.withColumn(
            "CUM_SUM",
            col("CUM_SUM") - sum(
                when(col(col_name) >= outlier, col(col_name))
            ).over(window_spec) 
        )

    # Find the maximum cumulative sum
    max_cum_sum = df.agg({"CUM_SUM": "max"}).collect()[0][0]

    # Calculate the decile and set the values in the column col_name2
    df = df.withColumn(
        col_name2,
        when(col(col_name) > 0, (11 - ceil(10 * col("CUM_SUM") / max_cum_sum))).otherwise(0)
    )
    
    # Set 'COL_NM2' to 10 where it's equal to 11
    df = df.withColumn(col_name2, when(col(col_name2) == 11, 10).otherwise(col(col_name2)))

    return df
```

So since I am runnning this code in Jupyter,it is giving me a warning a lot of times that :- WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
Now because of this one of the function call is working, but when I call the next function call it gives error - Connection Refused or just keeps on runnning forever.

I understand this has to do with partitions but since I am new to spark not really able to figure out how to tweak the code for errorless and faster execution. Really appreacite everyone's help on this.

Thank You !

Comment: It's only slow at the next function, because spark uses lazy execution. Your function is not actually calculated before you call the second function. The warning you get is because of your window not being partitioned. This means you calculate the cumsum over all the rows in the dataframe. This is done on the driver and therefore not parallelized and slow.